# jquery - How to limit selection to children of a cloned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of names:

```
var names = ['john', 'ted', 'pam'];
```

in the document I have this div:

```
<div id="template">
  Name: <input type="text" class="fname" />
  Age: <input type="text" class="age" />
</div>
```

for each name in the array I want to create inputs for name and age and pre-fill name. in the loop I am doing this:

```
var myitem = $('#template').clone().removeAttr('id');
```

Now before adding the new nodes to the dom I want to stuff the name, so I need to select `.fname`, not all that there is in the document, but those (in this case 1) that is inside `myitem`.

So I want to tell jQuery, *select elements with a class of `foo` **in the scope of** my variable*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.foo', myitem)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways, one is to use the `find()` method on the returned object, the other is to use the second argument to the jQuery function i.e.

```
var firstWay=myitem.find(".foo");
var secondWay=$(".foo", myitem);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$variable.find( selector );` should do the trick, assuming it's a jQuery object.